# отступ сверху между блоками

Tags: css

как убрать отступ между блоками?

```html
<div class="div">
<p >some text</p>
<div class="div2">another text</div></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вопрос быстрее ответят, если вы воспользуетесь вставкой кода, который можно будет сразу поправить. На панели инструментов при редактировании сообщений  есть такая кнопка

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите свойство для

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

И еще , как вы используете разметку ?

`<div class="div2">another text</div></div>`

Зачем вам два закрывающих блока `div`?

**UPD:** Не заметил разметку, почитайте про форматирование и качество кода